# Insertion sort in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I've written a stable implementation of insertion sort, that sorts an array in ascending order.

Please let me know of any improvements/optimisations that can be made.

```
import java.util.List;

public class InsertionSort {
    public static void start(List<Integer> arrayToSort){
        for(int i = arrayToSort.size() - 1; i > 0; i--){    // i is the leftmost index of sorted elements
            // j is the index at which the new element inserted in the sorted part of the array
            for(int j = arrayToSort.size() - 1; j >= i; j--){
                if(arrayToSort.get(i - 1) > arrayToSort.get(j)){
                    insert(i - 1, j + 1, arrayToSort);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void insert(int source, int destination, List<Integer> arrayToSort){
        arrayToSort.add(destination, arrayToSort.get(source));
        arrayToSort.remove(source);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Unnecessary work

Consider a list of \$n\$ elements, then `insert(1,0)` will move approximately \$2n\$ elements in the array when all it really had to do was swap the two elements.

Note that an optimised `insert(source, destination)` only needs to move `source - destination` elements. As this looks like self-learning or possibly homework, I'll leave the details to you.

## Use binary search

You can binary search for the insertion point to improve the performance even further.

Comment: Binary search works only on sorted arrays, but the array is not sorted... rigth?

Comment: @Caridorc The insertion is always into the sorted part of the array. After `x` iterations of insertion sort, the `x` first elements are always sorted. Which means you can use binary search within those `x` elements to find the next insertion point.

Comment: Clever! +1 padpadpad

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it's fine, just a few notes:

```
public static void start(List<Integer> arrayToSort){
```

- There should be a space before "{".
- By using `List<Integer>` you're losing memory and speed when compared to `int[]`
- If you work with objects, you can make it more general
- This method `start`s neither this array, nor anything else.
- It should be called `sort`

---

```
 private static void insert(int source, int destination, List<Integer> arrayToSort){
```

I'd call it `insertAndRemove` or simply `move` as this is what it does. I'd also call the argument just `array` as this method doesn't care what it's meant for.